# Defining Constant in Static Nested Class

Tags: java

I am defining constants in Static Nested Class

```
public final class Constants {

public static final class LDAP {
    public static final String BASE_DN = "dc=example,dc=com";
    public static final String OU = "ou";
    public static final String CN = "cn";
    public static final String SN = "sn";
    public static final String GID_NUMBER = "gidNumber";
    public static final String UID_NUMBER = "uidNumber";
    public static final String HOME_DIRECTORY = "homeDirectory";
    public static final String UID = "uid";
    public static final String TELE_PHONE_NUMBER = "telephoneNumber";
    public static final String USER_PASSWORD = "userPassword";

    public static final String OBJECT_CLASS = "objectclass";
    public static final String OBJECT_CLASS_TOP = "top";
    public static final String OBJECT_CLASS_PERSON = "person";
    public static final String OBJECT_CLASS_POSIX_ACCOUNT = "posixAccount";
}

public static final class GenericStringConstan {
    public static final String EMAIL_REPLACE_CHAR_FROM = "@";
    public static final String EMAIL_REPLACE_CHAR_TO = "__";
    public static final String BACK_SLASH = "/";
    public static final String FORWARD_SLASH = "/";

}

}
```

Is that a best practice to do so? With this I am trying to grouping all constant in single class.
What are the pros and cons with these approach.
Or It is better do create a separate class for different type of constants?

Answer (score 1):

I don't like this approach because your class Constants becomes nothing else that part of the package path:

```
my.package.path.Constants.LDAP.UID
```

and still it's difficult to find any constant because the file can be huge.
I'd create a different file for each group of constants/enums.

Comment: Agreed with your point, but what would be the technical issues? Please correct me, when Constant class gets compiled, compiler creates 3 different class files(in my case). So in a way it is one of the same thing of having 3 different class or group them in nested static class.

Comment: I'm talking about development time: when I have to maintain projects with hundreds of constants in the same file, sometimes it's difficult to know if I should create another one or if one of the already created matches what I need. As you say in runtime several classes will be created, the only problem there could be you'd need to declare several private constructors to ensure nobody instantiate them.

Answer (score 0):

If your constants are strictly connected with enclosing class you can have them inside nested class.
If not (If you have at least 2 different classes where you want to use your constants) you should declare your class with constants as a top-level class with private constructor to unable to instantiate this class.